# Display images in RecycleView using Picaso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a bunch of local images named image01.png ... image30.png. I want to display those images using recylceview (for better memory handling) in a fragment. I would like to use Picasso to load and resize those image.

All solutions I found is using an adapter. Can anybody suggest any easier way to impalement this without using adapter? Thanks lot in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular you do not want to use an adapter? They are pretty trivial to make and learning to write an adapter will make future development easier for you

Comment: Please check my answer. If you could show some example of your code, I could show you how to add an adapter to your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Nic My only reason not to use adapter is im not too comfortable with adapter. Im planning to do a simple task (as far as I understand) and if I can avoid using adapter I would like to do so :)

Comment: @munimisu The only way you will get comfortable with adapters is if you learn to make them. Look up a tutorial on RecyclerViews and adapters and actually learn the process. It will make you a better coder in the long run and will make things a lot easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use caching capability of Picasso to efficiently load your images.

If that is the case then why don't you use an adapter with Recycler View.  Provide adapter only the name of of the images and finally inside the adapter use Picasso to load the images.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Yes, you are right, I want to use picasso for caching, memory management and ease of resizing. Do you have any code snippet for the adapter that will use picasso for loading image? Thanks!

Comment: It will be the most optimised solution.  Just make sure Picasso is using in memory LRU cache.

Answer (score 1):

Any `ViewGroup` that dynamically populates its children with data from a data source like an `ArrayList` or a database does so using an adapter. A `RecyclerView` (or a `ListView`, `GridView`, `ViewPager`, etc.) cannot function without an adapter. If you do not want to use an adapter, use a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How well is memory managed if I go this route? I dont want to cause any crash for out of memory issue.

Comment: If you have very many images, this is not the right way to go. Even hardcoding 30 images to a layout seems like a bad idea to me. @NicRobertson is right in advising you to learn to make adapters. If you are time-bound, I can write a simple adapter for you (if you give me all the details I would need--we can take this up on chat), but learning to write an adapter would be the best decision in the long run.